# strnlen does not exist in gcc-4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 - how to define it?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I'm building a cross platform OS X version of the latest [dcraw.c](https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/dcraw.c) I'm doing this on OS X 10.6.8 to have the PPC compatibility. Now my problem is that strnlen seems to get used in the latest version of the program and it does not exist on 10.6.8 and gcc gives me messages like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_strnlen", referenced from:
...
Undefined symbols for architecture ppc:
  "_strnlen", referenced from:
...
```

So, I'd like to just define strnlen but don't quite know how.

**Q:** Can anyone please provide a working definition of strnlen to use in dcraw.c?

My gcc compilation command is this btw:

```
gcc -o dcraw -O4 -Wall -force_cpusubtype_ALL -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc dcraw.c -lm -DNODEPS
```

Comment: Something looks wrong there - `strnlen()` should be part of the standard C library, and I believe `_strnlen` is the linker symobl name for that function.  That's one thing to check - is the symbol name in the library using 0, 1, or 2 underscores before it?

Comment: The source code refers to `strnlen`, not `_strnlen`. `strnlen` is defined by POSIX. Does `man strnlen` tell you anything? If so, it should tell you what compile-time options you need to specify to enable it.

Comment: Hmm, aren't `-arch i386` and `-arch ppc` mutually exclusive?

Comment: @ash nope this builds a universal binary that runs from 10.4 through 10.11

Comment: @C.O. very interesting.

Comment: Try `gcc -v -o dcraw -O4 -Wall -force_cpusubtype_ALL -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc dcraw.c -lm -DNODEPS` to find the exact library paths being linked, and then check the symobls of those libs. `nm <lib> | grep strnlen` should help.

Comment: It's not availab in 10.4, only since 10.7. See `size_t   strnlen(const char *, size_t) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);`.

Comment: @ash `strnlen()` is not in a C11 draft of Apr 2011

Comment: @chux - ok.  Thank you.

Comment: @C.O. if the strnlen function just isn't available with the version of the compiler, then HelloWorld's answer is likely the best solution.  Using the `gcc -v` and `nm` commands should get you close to an answer there.  Compiling a small sample program is a good way to determine if the compiler can find the function at all.

Comment: @ash It really is not available on 10.6 and on 10.7 all the PPC stuff has been removed by Apple so I can't use that. Where do I best put HelloWorld's answer?

Comment: I would put it in the file you want to compile `dcraw.c`. If there are more of them create a header file and place it there.

Comment: If this is third-party code, I would put that answer into a library and add `-l<libname>` to the gcc compilation line.  Unless it's opensource and you can (a) contribute the solution, and (b) find `#ifdef` constructs to properly detect when the function needs to be included.  If this is your own app, I would either just put it in an existing source file, or (my preference) in a new source file added to the project.

Comment: suggest, at the command line: `man strnlen`  If an appropriate man page is displayed, then the problem is in how your compiling the source code.   I will assume that in your source code you have the statement: `#include <string.h>`

Comment: there is no way the binaries for the two different CPUs will run on either machine because the machine code ops/etc are completely different.  However, library's for a specific machine will run on that specific machine and a source file can be compiled (most of the time) on the machine it is to run on.

Comment: per this link: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strnlen.3.html>  the function strnlen() is available,  It may be necessary to have `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE = 200809L`  as a compiler parameter or a #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 20089L statement before the #include statements

Comment: your compile statement has two different 'arch' parameters.  `-arch i386 -arch ppc`  the gcc compiler will only pay attention to one of those parameters, probably the second 'arch' parameter (or issue a warning/error message)

Comment: @user3629249 as discussed in the comments above the two 'arch' parameters are valid and result in a univeral binary build that has both the Power PC and the Intel executable and runs on OS X 10.4 PPC through 10.11 Intel. We've been using that for years and it's well tested...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[strnlen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strnlen.3.html) is a GNU extension and also specified in POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008). If `strnlen` is not available (it is since 10.7) use the following replacement.

```
// Use this if strnlen is missing.
size_t strnlen(const char *str, size_t max)
{
    const char *end = memchr (str, 0, max);
    return end ? (size_t)(end - str) : max;
}
```

Comment: `strlen()` is not a safe replacement if the buffer may not be null terminated.

Comment: It's not just a GNU extension; it's [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strnlen.html).

Comment: Minor: remove extra `;` in `size_t maxlen);`

Comment: @HelloWorld Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW - this only works when `sizeof char == 1`, correct?  I suspect that's perfectly adequate for the Op's question.

Comment: my understanding is that sizeof(char) is specifically defined as 1 in the c standard

Comment: Yes, sizeof(char) is always 1 (see §6.5.3.4 C++ `When (the sizeof operator is) applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.`). In C and C++ a char is a byte but a byte is implementation-defined (in C++ see §1.7/1, in C99 see §3.6). The width of a char is defined in `CHAR_BIT` which is 8 in most cases. The only requirement is that it is at **least** large enough to contain a member of the basic execution character set. But sizeof still returns 1.

Comment: @seb-mtl it *was* a GNU extension. It can no longer be called an "extension" now that it's part of the spec.

Comment: @Craig: Do you have a link?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strnlen.html 

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strnlen