# Is strnlen function supported in C++, on codeblocks ide?

Tags: c++, c++11

My program is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    const static size_t maxbuf=128;
    const char * s1="String one";
    char sd1[maxbuf];
    printf("length is %ld",strnlen(sd1,maxbuf));
    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
 strnlen was not declared in this scope
```

Questions:

1. Why I am not able to use `strnlen` function in *C++* on my *codeblocks IDE*?
2. Is their a good alternative to `strnlen`?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: strnlen was not declared in this scope

Comment: check where strnlen fucntion is defined and include that library.

Comment: Why don't you have [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)-s?

Comment: strnlen() is a posix function, cstring only hoists standard C library functions.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string` and `std::cout` etc.?

Comment: @EdHeal what? C++ isn't just C with classes?

Comment: No it is not  C++ is another language

Comment: @EdHeal hold up, let me re-write my comment.

Comment: @EdHeal <joke> what? C++ isn't just C with classes? </joke>

Comment: Does `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`, before including the headers, solve?

Comment: @DevashishLohani: Don't confound IDE with compiler. Mostly when IDE supports several compilers.

Comment: @black unfortunately that's not working...

Answer (score 2):

`strnlen` is a GNU extension and also specified in [POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strlen.html). If `strnlen` is not available, which can happen when such extension is not supported, use the following replacement.

```
// Use this if strnlen is missing.
size_t strnlen(const char *str, size_t max)
{
    const char *end = memchr (str, 0, max);
    return end ? (size_t)(end - str) : max;
}
```

I gave an answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468480/strnlen-does-not-exist-in-gcc-4-2-1-on-mac-os-x-10-6-8-how-to-define-it/32468556#32468556).

Comment: Thank you but can you suggest me a complier (or a IDE) in windows where strnlen will work without this implementation? Is there a similar alternative to it to make it work on codeblocks ide? Actually its working perfectly in my Mac with xcode without any further implementations.

Comment: IDE != compiler != linker != libraries. This is not related to the compiler or the IDE. Just because they are bundled sometimes (e.g. VS is shipped with a compiler and a linker, ...) that doesn't mean they are the same. The IDE is just the environment where you write your source in and can setup your build chain - nothing else. Why don't you use the function I posted when the extension is not available on your platform?

Comment: The general rule of thumb is try to depend on standard library, when possible. Are you dealing with legacy code? Do you _need_ to deal with c-strings instead of `std::string`?