# Python: Installed Anaconda, but can't import numpy or matplotlib in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Python, so maybe there is a simple solution to this. I installed Anaconda and thought everything would be straightforward, but even though Jupyter works fine I can't import numpy and matplotlib into my notebook. Instead I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1e0540761e0c> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
      3 plt.plot(vals)

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    120 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    121 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 122 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
    123 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    124 from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py in <module>()
     31 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     32 
---> 33 import numpy as np
     34 import numpy.ma as ma
     35 

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    144         return loader(*packages, **options)
    145 
--> 146     from . import add_newdocs
    147     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    148                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, \
     13                 obj2sctype, zeros

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     12         os.environ[envkey] = '1'
     13         env_added.append(envkey)
---> 14 from . import multiarray
     15 for envkey in env_added:
     16     del os.environ[envkey]

ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 10): Symbol not found: _strnlen
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/../../../..//libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/../../../..//libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
```

Since both packages show up in `$ conda list` its probably some kind of linking error(?), but that is unfortunately something a beginner can hardly solve for himself. Can anyone help?

Comment: At a first glance this looks like a serious problem with your installation as the error refers to some `.dylib` (DYnamic LIBrary) file which has to do with NumPy internals, not with your code.

Comment: @ForceBru I did nothing else than downloading & installing Anaconda, opening a Jupyter notebook and running a few simple scripts.

Comment: I see, but this is still a pretty odd error for me as it's complaining about the fact that the `_strnlen` C standard library symbol is missing, and this symbol is kinda standard, _it should be present_, but it isn't...

Comment: I am on a fairly old system (OS X 10.6.8), but I have Python 3.5 and all the packages installed fine and are up to date.

Comment: @ForceBru It seems that `_strnlen` is indeed missing in 10.6.8, see [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/SnowLeopardProblems) and [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/SnowLeopardProblems). Is there a way to add it manually? It would be really depressing if I couldn't use SciPy due to this.

Comment: once I had a similar issue with some missing symbols on a jailbroken iPhone and compiled a newer C stdlib myself and inserted it into my device. Everything just froze and failed to boot. I ended up restoring iOS and losing the jailbreak, of course. I assume, things can go even worse on a Mac. To my mind, patching stdlib or trying to compile its newer version yourself isn't a good idea, given that it's much easier to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problem is possibly that you're running a pretty old Mac OS X version as `_strnlen` wasn't even available [until 10.7 release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32468480/4354477).

Anaconda is built for at least OS X 10.7 (according to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/m/#!topic/anaconda/QxVJifuRWiI)), so you're probably out of luck here and a possible solution would be to upgrade the system.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so If I correctly understand what you are saying I propose that you add the package in the same folder your python file is located in. If possible add the code you have used to import the data so I can located any possible mistakes

Comment: The code is cited at the beginning of the error message.

Comment: Okay so did you try what I mentioned? The problem is that your problem can't locate the package thus, you get the error
Expected in: flat namespace
 in /anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/../../../..//libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib

If what I mentioned initially doesn't work try adding your package in your python 3.5 folder in the folder packages

Comment: @LamprosTzanetos I tried to copy the `numpy-1.11.2-py35_0` folder to the project dir, but that gives the same error message.

Comment: I have faced a similar problem in the past. You have to locate the packages folder not the project dir. If you can't find add you program files as well as the package in a new folder and try running the program again.